# Is "www.example.com" split up by local DNS server to be used in different query stages?

Tags: dns

If I want to go to "www.example.com" and I do not have the mapping in chache, does my local DNS server split up "www.example.com", only sending the portion of the address necessary in the query to the appropriate name server?

e.g is only the .com part sent to the root server? Or is the entire www.example.com sent, and the root servers decides which part of that string is important for the query?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The whole name queried for is sent, always.

The resolution process is described in detail in RFC 1034.